# OpenAPI 3 Swagger UI not working on Spring 2.7.12 with Spring Security OAuth 2

Tags: spring-boot, spring-security, swagger-ui, spring-security-oauth2, springdoc-openapi-ui

I have upgraded my Spring version to 2.7.12 and migrating from SpringFox Swagger 2 to springdoc-openapi 3 (Swagger 3).

The Swagger config API is working fine but due to `WebMvcConfig` in my application, the api-docs api response is coming *encrypted* as a JWT token.

I tried following options:

1. Ignoring the Swagger URLs in `WebMVConfig` configuration classes.
2. Added resource handlers.
3. Added custom HTTP converters for `StringHttpMessageConverter` and `ByteArrayHttpMessageConverter`.

```java
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
public class WebSecurityConfiguration extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

  @Override
  public void configure(WebSecurity web) {

    web.ignoring().antMatchers("/**");
  }

  @Override
  protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
    http.authorizeRequests().antMatchers("/**").permitAll();
  }


@Configuration
public class OpenApiConfig {
  @Bean
  public OpenAPI customOpenAPI() {
    return new OpenAPI()
        .components(new Components())
        .info(new Info().title("CONTACT Management").description(
            "This is a sample Spring Boot RESTful service using springdoc-openapi and OpenAPI 3.").version("3.0.0"));
  }
}


@Configuration
@EnableWebMvc
public class WebMvcConfig implements WebMvcConfigurer {

  @Autowired
  private RequestInterceptor requestInterceptor;

  @Value("${allowed.headers}")
  private String allowedHeaders;

  @Override
  public void configureMessageConverters(@NotNull List<HttpMessageConverter<?>> converters) {

    WebMvcConfigurer.super.configureMessageConverters(converters);
    converters.add(0, new MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter(provideObjectMapper()));
    converters.add(new ByteArrayHttpMessageConverter());
    converters.add(new StringHttpMessageConverter());
  }

  @Bean
  public ObjectMapper provideObjectMapper() {
    return new ObjectMapper()
        .setDefaultPropertyInclusion(JsonInclude.Include.NON_NULL)
        .disable(DeserializationFeature.FAIL_ON_UNKNOWN_PROPERTIES);
  }

  @Override
  public void addCorsMappings(CorsRegistry registry) {
    registry.addMapping("/**").exposedHeaders(Constants.AUTHORIZATION_TOKEN).
        allowedHeaders(allowedHeaders.split(","));
  }

  @Override
  public void addResourceHandlers(ResourceHandlerRegistry registry) {
    registry.addResourceHandler("/swagger-ui/**")
        .addResourceLocations("classpath:/META-INF/resources/");
    registry.addResourceHandler("/webjars/**")
        .addResourceLocations("classpath:/META-INF/resources/webjars/");
  }

  @Override
  public void addArgumentResolvers(List<HandlerMethodArgumentResolver> argumentResolvers) {
    argumentResolvers.add(new PageableHandlerMethodArgumentResolver());
  }

  @Override
  public void addInterceptors(InterceptorRegistry registry) {
    registry.addInterceptor(requestInterceptor);
  }

}
```

```xml
   <parent>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
    <version>2.7.12</version>
    <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
   </parent>

     <dependency>
      <groupId>org.springframework.security.oauth</groupId>
      <artifactId>spring-security-oauth2</artifactId>
      <version>2.3.6.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.springdoc</groupId>
      <artifactId>springdoc-openapi-ui</artifactId>
      <version>1.7.0</version>
    </dependency>


    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.springdoc</groupId>
      <artifactId>springdoc-openapi-webmvc-core</artifactId>
      <version>1.7.0</version>
    </dependency>
```

[[Swagger UI](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IuLD6.png)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sOaxJ.png)

Comment: I have also encountered such issue with encoded responses for `/docs/open-api` endpoints. Adding `ByteArrayHttpMessageConverter` as the **first** converter (you have it second in you code) in the body of `configureMessageConverters()` method resolved this issue. Found the answer on the official springdoc-openapi GitHub page [here](https://github.com/springdoc/springdoc-openapi/issues/2143#issuecomment-1474981955).